# How to affect front page by plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I'm creating a plugin to remove some `WooCommerces` action, but my plugins seems not loading in the front page, only in admin page.

Code is like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price');
```

I added `die('something is wrog');` in the code, just to make sure the plugin is working, but that message is showing up only in the admin page.

What I need to do to my plugin to affect front page?

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is to remove that function/action only on the front page (not clear from your question), then this code

```
    if (is_front_page) {
       remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary',
 'woocommerce_template_single_price');

    }
```

This code needs to be outside of the 'admin' code area of the plugin. See this link for documentation on `is_front_page()` https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page

If that is not your question, then please edit your question to provide more detail.

Comment: My front page seems like not detecting existence of my plugin, only admin is reacting, no matter what function I call.

Comment: My first guess is that there is no 'hook' in your plugin to add the plugins functionality to a page/post. Take a look at the "WordPress Plugin Hooks" section of https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin , and the other pages linked on that page.  Somewhere in your plugin there needs to be a 'hook' that will let the plugin do something on a post/page.

Comment: I'm guessing the same, I'll take a look at the documentation, then I'll let you know my results, thanks!

Comment: As I tested, my plugin is affecting front page, but just not affecting WooCommerce product's page